# Calculating sales per hour

Tags: sql-server, loops

I am trying to calculate inventory sales based on missing inventory broken up into hours per day. (Each hour has a sequence number that references the time stamp...ie sequence#1 = 0:00-1:00). I need to get the average sales per hour over the course of a 3 month period. On top of that I also need to throw out upreadings in inventory.
Here is a snippet of my data:

[image]

UPDATE:
My plan is to take the current Inventory level(InvValue) and subtract it agains the previous inventory level(InvValue) for that hour. My problem is I don't know how to format the loop in order to organize the data to the right Hour(inv_sequence)

My end goal is to have:
hour 1 average : hour 2 average : hour 3 average
etc.

Comment: what does _I also need to throw out upreadings in inventory_ mean?

Comment: My inventory is in relation to Fluid in a tank. I would like to give a 0 reading to the hours in which we are refilling the tank as the "sales" will show up as negative sales for that hour and miscue the data.

Answer (score 1):

"average sales per hour" = count of total sales / (days * 24)

You are either overcomplicating things, or your specification of the task is not accurate,,,

Comment: I need the average of 3 months of data for each time fragment in the day. IE. i need to take my sales from midnight - 1AM over the last 30 days and average the sales over the last 3 months. I need to do this for each hour.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the Average of Inventory per Hour?